# Selecting only one element in the jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I limit an event to a single element in a jQuery collection?

In the case below, I've tried using `.one()` to limit the behaviour (inserting the `<li class='close'>Close</li>` line of HTML) to a single instance. The behaviour does indeed happen only once, but on EVERY matched element of `$( "ul>li>a" )`. How do I make it happen only once, to only ONE of the matched elements in the collection?

Any ideas?

```
$( "ul>li>a" ).one(
 "click",    
 function(){
  $( "ul ul")
  .prepend("<li class='close'>Close</li>")
 }
 );
```

Thanks in advance.

-AS

Answer (score 28):

A `jQuery` selection returns an array. Therefore `$("selection")[0]` can work. However there are better abstracted methods for this, like `.get(0)` or `.first()` (in case you're looking for the first element of the selection/array).

**$("selection").get(index)** returns the pure DOM element (at that specific index) of the selection, and is *not* wrapped in the jQuery object.

**$("selection").first()** returns the *first* element of the selection, and *wraps* it in a jQuery object.

So if you don't necessarely want to return the **first** element, but still want jQuery functionality, you can do `$($("selection").get(index))`.

Given your situation, this should work fine:

```
// bind the 'onclick' event only on the first element of the selection
$( "ul>li>a" ).first().click(function() {
    $( "ul ul").prepend("<li class='close'>Close</li>");
});
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
$($( "ul>li>a" ).get(0)).click(function() {
    $( "ul ul").prepend("<li class='close'>Close</li>");
});
```

And this:

```
$($( "ul>li>a" )[0]).click(function() {
    $( "ul ul").prepend("<li class='close'>Close</li>");
});
```

---

I must disagree with Ryan, working on the CSS selection string to filter the result is rather expensive compared to the native JavaScript array functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/), it selects the first element:

```
$( "ul>li>a" ).first().one('click',    
     function(){
        $( "ul ul").prepend("<li class='close'>Close</li>")
     }
 );
```

[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is used, as you already noticed, to handle an event only **once**.

Comment: @SLaks: I was too fast with copy and past ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the index of the element you want to work with.

If your selector returns more than one element you can do one of a couple things...
You can isolate your elements by giving them a class or id attribute in your html and alter the selector to select only the class/id of the element/s you wish to select or you can specify the index of the element you're trying to work with. The later method is a bit sloppy but works as long as your page structure doesn't ever change.

So for the first method I spoke of you'd change your selector to this after applying a class/id to your elements:

```
$("ul>li>a.class")
or
$("ul>li>a#id")
```

For the second method I mentioned you'd change your selector to this:

```
$("ul>li>a:eq(index)")
```

Where index is the zero based index of the element you're trying to select.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method, which will return a new jQuery object containing only the first element in the original one.

However, in your case, you might as well use the (equivalent) [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$("ul > li > a:first").click(function() { ... });
```

If you only want to handle the first `click` event and ignore any subsequent clicks, you'll need to use `.one()`, like you already are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine first() with one():

```
$( "ul>li>a" ).first().one('click', function () {});
```

More general:

```
$( "ul>li>a:eq(n)" ).one('click', function () {});
```